# nvm-windows: not able to run globally installed software

Tags: node.js, express, nvm

I have installed different version of node using nvm on windows 7. 
Currently I am using node v8.0.0. I installed express globally

```
npm install -g express
```

But when I try to create a new app using `express testapp`, I get the 
following error message:

```
'express' is not recognized as an internal or extenal command.
```

This problem is with all the globally installed node modules.

Answer (score 0):

got it! I have to install express-generator and then give the express  command